Unable to compile LLVM libc due to warnings treated as errors
I'm trying to compile the LLVM libc project on Ubuntu, but I keep running into an issue where warnings are being treated as errors, specifically related to type conversion. Here is the relevant error message:
In file included from /home/chongchuanlong/src/LLVM/llvm-project-18.1.8.src/libc/src/__support/CPP/stringstream.h:16,
                 from /home/chongchuanlong/src/LLVM/llvm-project-18.1.8.src/libc/src/__support/StringUtil/error_to_string.cpp:14:
/home/chongchuanlong/src/LLVM/llvm-project-18.1.8.src/libc/src/__support/integer_to_string.h:160:58: error: conversion from ‘long unsigned int’ to ‘unsigned char’ may change value [-Werror=conversion]
  160 | template <size_t radix> using Custom = details::Fmt<radix>;
      |                                                          ^
...
cc1plus: all warnings being treated as errors

I have already tried setting the following CMake flags:
cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -DLLVM_ENABLE_PROJECTS="libc" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS="-Wno-error" -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS="-Wno-error" -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/local/llvm/libc ../llvm-project-18.1.8.src/llvm

And I also tried:
make CFLAGS="-Wno-error=format-truncation"

And I also tried:
env CXXFLAGS="-Wno-ignored-qualifiers -Wno-stringop-truncation -Wno-cast-function-type" make

And I also add set(CMAKE_COMPILE_WARNING_AS_ERROR OFF) at top of the llvm-project-18.1.8.src/libc/CMakeLists.txt
But the problem persists.
How can I compile the project successfully without treating these warnings as errors?
Thanks in advance for any help!

This is probably best fixed by changing the header to not do the implicit conversion - if you raise a ticket on https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/ and tag me or jhuber6 it's likely to be fixed in tree. Otherwise suggest grep through cmake looking for -Werror and remove it locally, though it really shouldn't be there in the first place.
